# Razor Web page Rendering

Tags: asp.net, .net, razor

I'm creating a custom web page base class (not to be confused with web forms or MVC), inheriting from `System.Web.WebPages.WebPage`.  What I would like to do is run some code when the web page renders.  In web forms, I would override the Render method to do this; however, all I see as an overridable method is RenderPage, which renders a different page  within the current rendered page.

Is there a method that gets run during rendering, or is that what the InitializePage method is for?

Thanks.

Comment: Depending on what you need to do, you could make a base controller class and do your logic in `OnActionExecuted` or `OnActionExecuting`.

Comment: Not MVC, Razor web pages, the web page version.

Comment: What are you trying to do when the page renders?  I'm the PM for Web Pages and Razor, btw.

Comment: @Erik For me, I'm more researching; was going to maybe wrap some architecture around it, not to change how it works, but to all my framework to tap into.  Nothing crucial though.  Great product, by the way.  You guys did a great job.

Comment: Thanks! If you have any specific questions feel free to tweet me @HumanCompiler or send me mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Razor engine doesn't really 'render' per say. It's basically a code generator that turns your Razor page into executable code of literal strings (HTML) and code blocks (expressions/code). It does this in its Execute() method that gets generated.

So when you create a custom template you might be able to override the Execute() method and do some pre or post processing, but you can't really affect anything inside of the generated code.

Render() in WebForms on the other hand is more of a component based interface since it can potentially intercept rendering from any control each of which has a Render() method that's responsible for generating its own output. In Razor this doesn't make a ton of sense since there are no controls (short of partials).

IAC, I'd recommend taking a look at your Razor pages in teh ASP.NET Temporary Files folder and checking out the source code. That will give you a pretty good idea what the generated code looks like and what you can potentially do in a custom template to intercept the output generation.